# What is the correct RE2 regex for extracting a substring from a string containing numbers, symbols and characters?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, re2

I am trying to extract the substring containing the "numbers,filename and extension" from a complex file name. This has to be repeated for a list of file names:

```
file1 = "Apple_Or_Orange_1_2_3_4_filename_1.pdf"
file2 = "Apple_Or_Orange_5_6_7_8_filename_2.pdf"
```

All of this is in a Google Sheet. Since this is in a Google Sheet, I'm trying to use the `spreadsheetApp.regextract()` function. This function only accepts RE2 format regex:

```
regex = "^[^Drive_By_Wire_Safety_Case_]\d|\w|."
```

But this is not producing the desired result. Expected output is:

```
output1 = "1_2_3_4_filename_1.pdf"
output2 = "5_6_7_8_filename_2.pdf"
```

Comment: Try `^Apple_Or_Orange_(.+)`. Or, if you have `Drive_By_Wire_Safety_Case_` there, use `^Drive_By_Wire_Safety_Case_(.+)`

Comment: Thanks! it worked

Answer (score 0):

You may extract the text using

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "^Apple_Or_Orange_(.+)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XsSMrr/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5EApple_Or_Orange_(.%2B)):

[image]

The `(.+)` is a *capturing group* that, when is used in the regex pattern, captures (a part of) a match and `REGEXEXTRACT` returns that part only.